# Apache Tomcat startup does not find neither JDK or JRE

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, environment-variables, windows-8.1

I need Apache Tomcat to run jsp projects in Eclipse on Windows 8.1 (64 bits).

I have installed both Java (jre and jdk) and Eclipse in Program Files.
And Tomcat in Program Files (x86).

Also I have created both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables. But when I run tomcat's startup.bat, it returns me the next message:
"Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined.
At least one of these environment variables is needed to run this program".

What Im doing wrong? I must install all programs in one of the two Program Files (x86 or normal)? I must specify the Program Files type in the environment variable somehow?

Comment: there are spaces in the vars path?

Comment: Did you define User level variables or System level? Did you add JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME to your PATH? What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: If you want to start Tomcat from within Eclipse you can define a server and start if from the server view, see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftomcat.html

Comment: @robermann Only between "Program" and "Files"

Comment: @mbs I defined them as System level variables. I didn't add or modify nothing at PATH variable.
And java -version returns me:
"java version 1.7.0_51
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: since you have spaces in the path you should surround it with ""

Comment: @Peter Yes, it was the first thing I do. I did it before in Debian (and i think also Ubuntu) some months ago and it runs perfectly. But in Windows 8 (and XP), ever I run a jsp file, Eclipse returns me a error about Tomcat.

Comment: @Beemo have u added the JAVA_Home varaible to ur system path?

Comment: as @Peter said use tomcat within eclipse...

Comment: ok, I'm going to "formalize" the answer; anyway, it is better avoiding spaces in paths when using batch scripting (alas, Windows still provides a "program files" default dir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the paths contain spaces, surround them with double quotes "

Comment: Now jsp works in Eclipse, but not when i enter localhost:8080 from Chrome. But in this moment that it's enough for me.